# How to handle deposit to account in double entry book keeping?

Tags: sql, postgresql, accounting

as far as I understand double entry book keeping consists of two pairs, debit and credit.
when someone gets credit the other person should get debit ( and sum should always be 0 ).

My question is what if a person wants to deposit inside his/her own account, how that is going to work? should we add both credit and debit for the account? if so how are we able to determine the balance of the account then?

My tables:

```sql
users (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        username VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
        created_at DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
    )

transaction_types (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20)
    )

transactions (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        type_id INTEGER REFERENCES transaction_types(id),
        user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id),
        amount DECIMAL(20, 10) NOT NULL,
        created_at DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
    )
```

When a transaction between two users happens, a row for giver with negative amount and a row for receiver with positive amount is inserted. what should happen when a user deposits to his own account?

I think I'm misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 1):

Not programming, but accounting basics.

SOmeone depositing into an account is two things:

- Adding money to your account
- Adding a debt to the person (or a general accout "money owed to external parties", though most systems will have accounts per person there).

Note that if this is to pay for something you did, this debt immediately is offset by the negative value of the account (as it owes you money).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, would you mind providing an example or an external link so I can understand completely what is going on?

Comment: Not really - i did not learn accounting in english and it is a long time. This is basic double book keeping. You bascially have 4 lists of accounts: Your assets, Your liability, Other entity assets, Other entity liabilities. The last 2 are to balance incoming and outgoing money. You do not "get money" - you ALSO get a debt towards somoene.

Comment: about getting "debt towards someone", so when a user deposits money, the website owes money to the user, where this "owed money" is stored? I'm asking from a database model perspective

Comment: Nope, the WEBSITE does not. Same as the car is not responsible for a fine. The BUSINESS or whatever entity is behind the website owes money. It is stored in the user account, which actually is directly a debt. See, he pays to AN account (i.e. a paypal account). THat is an asset of the company. The company now also has a debt towards the user. Balanced.

Comment: You should definitely get a beginner book into double entry bookkeeping. There is a dummies book for that (financial accounting for dummies) and that should get you a basic overview also of all the terms used.

Comment: I really appreciate you answering my questions, what I'm trying to implement is a very basic banking system, and when I said the website owes money to the user I meant the bank owing money, the money which the user deposits can be transferred to other users, and the user can also withdraw it, when I'm implementing the pair for a transfer, two rows get inserted, one for receiver with positive amount and one for sender with negative amount, this is all good, but my question is when a user deposits to bank, this means a transaction between bank and user, how should I insert the rows?

Comment: and again, thank you so much for answering these, unfortunately I have very limited time for this task, but when I get more free time, I will definitely check the book you mentioned.